# Javascript setTimeout scope error or bug?

Tags: javascript

I need to make a pexeso game as my homework to school. I have basically implemented the whole game, but I am stuck at setTimeout issue.

This is the main logic of the game:

```
let firstCard = null;
let secondCard = null;
let points = 0;
let turnedCards = 0;

const createCard = (cityName) => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.classList.add('card');
    card.innerText = cityName;
    card.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (firstCard == null) {
            firstCard = card;
            card.classList.add('revealed');
        } else if (secondCard == null) {
            secondCard = card;
            card.classList.add('revealed');
            if (firstCard.innerText == secondCard.innerText && firstCard != secondCard && !firstCard.classList.contains('final') && !secondCard.classList.contains('final')) {
                updateScore();
                firstCard.classList.add('final');
                secondCard.classList.add('final');
            } else {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    if (!firstCard.classList.contains('final')) {
                        firstCard.classList.remove('revealed');
                    }
                    if (!secondCard.classList.contains('final')) {
                        secondCard.classList.remove('revealed');
                    }

                },2000);
            }


            firstCard = null;
            secondCard = null;
        }
    });
    gameArea.appendChild(card);
}
```

the setTimeout method is there to provide you some time to see turned cards. Now, when I start this game, I always get

```
main.js:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
```

Which come from the firstCard.classList and secondCard.classList in the setTimeout method. I mean, how can firstCard and secondCard be null, if i explicitly assigned value to them just before the method executed?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: `firstCard = null; secondCard = null;` is run before the asynchronous callback is executed

Comment: Sorry sir what does it mean? I am not javascript guy and took the class just out of an interest. And how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out in a comment, the error is most likely due by the assignments

```
firstCard = null;
secondCard = null;
```

which run before the `setTimeout` callback. In fact, the callback runs with 2000ms delay, so most likely after that assignment has been executed.

I am not sure if this will break the logic of the game, but a solution might be to move these assignments inside the `setTimeout` callback itself (as well as in the "then" branch of the larger `if` block).

```
if (firstCard.innerText == secondCard.innerText && firstCard != secondCard && !firstCard.classList.contains('final') && !secondCard.classList.contains('final')) {
  updateScore();
  firstCard.classList.add('final');
  secondCard.classList.add('final');
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
} else {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (!firstCard.classList.contains('final')) {
        firstCard.classList.remove('revealed');
    }
    if (!secondCard.classList.contains('final')) {
        secondCard.classList.remove('revealed');
    }
    firstCard = null;
    secondCard = null;
  },2000);
}
```

Mozilla's guide to `setTimeout` might be a good resource to help with this issue:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: I tried this solution, but it did not help. The feature of turning cards works now, but the game is broken,. I use the pointers to hold references to the turned cards, so they wont reset.

Comment: Well, I don't know how the whole program works - but with a quick look, I think you need to reassign the cards to `null` also when a matching pair is discovered. If that's the case, you may repeat those assignments in the other branch of the `if`. I have updated the answer to reflect that.